# Where can I find the Eye of Power Scepter recipe?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm trying to find the Eye of Power Scepter recipe, and can't seem to find it. I thought it might be in Sparkfly Fen, but I have failed to find it. I'd like to get this recipe so I can complete my recipes, as it's one of a handful I don't have yet. Where do I find this recipe?

Comment: Judging by the level and the skin, it's probably a rare drop from Twilight Arbor explorable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not going to like the answer I've got for you... but I suspect that asking your question here will not really get you closer to finding out where to get this recipe.

The answer is probably among the best-kept secrets in GW2, as those few who have the recipes craft this sceptre and sell it for far more than its worth, simply because of its mystique. Those that have it do not want to give up their monopoly. It's nothing more than a level 60 green sceptre - you can buy a far better one (rare) for far less in-game money. But you probably already know that.

The closest you'll likely get is this:

- The recipe is soulbound or at least account bound (which is why it's not for sale on the TP)
- Your best area to start searching is Sparkfly Fen. Why? Because the item's skin is "verdant", implying Maguuma, and its level is 60 (the only area including this level is 55-65 Sparkfly Fen).
- If you search the web, you'll find references to claims that it's sold by a vendor who is only available after some dynamic event, or that it's a (very) rare drop from certain mobs in this area. I'm sure you would've tried all the heart vendors and found that it's not available there. So start running around Sparkfly Fen and cross your fingers.

Good luck... and I'd actually recommend that, if you *do* find it, you don't post the answer anywhere, but keep it a secret. Let's keep some of the mystery alive in GW2 :-)

Comment: I am pretty sure if I ever find out I'm going to spread the information everywhere

Comment: Thank you. This is the closest to an answer I've ever gotten so far. I'll keep looking. And, yes, I do know I could buy (and make) better ones. It's sort of a "completionist" thing for me, I just want to collect as many of the collectible recipes I can.